# NullPointerException loading scene graph from FXML, integrated with Spring

Tags: java, spring, javafx, fxml

I want to contruct a controller for my JavaFX application, which automatically loads the FXML file "view.fxml" into the member "Parent root" and takes constructor arguments (in this example "String message").

I made it work just fine, but then I tried to instantiate a DemoController instance using Spring and I receive a "NullPointerException: Root cannot be null". This irritates me, because the instantiation of the bean using Spring seems to be working just fine and yet it doesn't load the FXML correctly. My only guess is that the directory structure might be messed up, but I cannot fix it and I would be very greatful for any help :)

Main.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        DemoController myController = (DemoController) context.getBean("myController");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(myController.getRoot()));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Game of Life");
        primaryStage.show();    

        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
    }
}
```

FXMLController.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;


public abstract class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    protected Parent root;

    protected String fxmlFilePath;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        loadFXML();
    }

    protected final void loadFXML() throws IOException {    
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFilePath));
        loader.setController(this);
        this.root = loader.load();
    }

    public Parent getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setFxmlFilePath(String fxmlFilePath) {
        this.fxmlFilePath = fxmlFilePath;
    }
}
```

DemoController.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class DemoController extends FXMLController {

    public DemoController(String message) {
         System.out.println(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        System.out.println("initializing");     
   }
```

}

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id = "myController" class = "DemoController">
      <constructor-arg value = "message"/>
      <property name = "fxmlFilePath" value = "/view.fxml"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

view.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</AnchorPane>
```

directory structure

- src

  - Beans.xml
  - view.fxml
  - (default package)

    - DemoController.java
    - FXMLController.java
    - Main.java

console output

```
message
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:336)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:194)
    at Main.start(Main.java:21)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application Main
```

A brief overview over the code:

- The main sets up the JavaFX environment and uses Spring to instantiate a DemoController. It displayes the scene graph given by the controller.
- The FXMLController is an abstract class, which encapuslates the loading of the FXML file and supplies a getter methods for the scene graph (getRoot()).
- The DemoController extends FXMLController and doesn't add much.
- Beans.xml supplies Spring with the necessary configuration information for the controller.
- view.fxml has only an AnchorPane and is essentially empty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't implement [`InitializingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html), so `afterPropertiesSet` is never invoked. Implementing this interface should fix the issue:

```
public abstract class FXMLController implements Initializable, InitializingBean {

    ...

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        loadFXML();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this cured my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything else looks fine here for you except the folder structure. For it to read the controller.fxml files, those should be in resource directory following the same structure as your controller.java. For ex: java/com.example.project.controller/MainController.java
resources/com.example.project.controller/MainController.fxml

If you do not have this folder structure, you would need to explicitly provide the path to your controller file as @FxmlView//("/Controller.fxml"). This would work in the IDE but when you package it, this may not work. So I would suggest to change the folder structure.

Also try using spring boot which would make it much easier.

Also look at below for reference.
https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver/issues/12#issuecomment-803475945